# grep doesn't work as expected

Tags: grep, regex

I'm trying to understand how grep deciding to take $ as regex, or as a searchable character.  My results show that grep is inconsistently deciding what $ means.

As such, I made a basic example:

```
$ cat testfile
$illy
$unset
```

Here I want to see if I can grab the line ending in "illy" using regex:

```
$ grep 'illy$' testfile
$illy
```

It seems to work, and it is interpreting the 'illy$' criteria as the $ being a regex to say "match this expression at the end of the line".  So my thinking now, is that grep interprets $ as a regex criteria, and not a string. So if I wanted to try and grep for '$illy', then this should not match anything because it's interpreting $ as regex.

However:

```
$ grep '$illy' testfile
$illy
```

Why does it find this line?  This proves that even grep doesn't know how to interpret the character $.  Let alone, myself trying to understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` by default uses [*Basic Regular Expressions*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BRE), and `$` is a special character in BRE's only at the end of an expression.

If you want `grep` to process pattern as an extended regexp, use `-E` option

```
-E, --extended-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular  expression  (ERE,  see
              below).
```

-

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ grep '$illy' test
$illy
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ grep -E '$illy' test
pilot6@Pilot6:~$

pilot6@Pilot6:~$ grep 'illy$' test
$illy
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ grep -E 'illy$' test
$illy
```

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge on this matter to elaborate. I always use `-E` when I want a regexp as a pattern.

Comment: This isn't answering my question and is removing focus away from what I'm trying to identify as a problem, or something I don't understand with regards to grep (and not egrep).  Why is grep non-deterministic in it's decision? (just so you know, I fully agree with your use of egrep, but I am specifically trying to work out how normal grep is working here).

Comment: The @steeldriver link explains it.

Comment: I copied a part of it.

Comment: This is brilliant. My first time using regex with grep, and I discover that grep uses $ as regex, except when it decides not to lol.  I can't mark steeldrivers answer as correct because it's only a reply.